# how to renew column values based on part of character value in another column using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large data frame with two columns. The right column I want to renew based on parts of the character values in the left column.

This is anexample:

```
df <- structure(list(content = c("my new info", "information2", 
"information3", "information4", "my new information2", "my new information3", 
"information5", "information6", "information7", "information8"
), content_new = c("no new info", "no new info", "no new info", 
"no new info", "no new info", "no new info", "no new info", "no new info", 
"no new info", "no new info")), .Names = c("content", "content_new"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))

print(df)

               content content_new
1          my new info no new info
2         information2 no new info
3         information3 no new info
4         information4 no new info
5  my new information2 no new info
6  my new information3 no new info
7         information5 no new info
8         information6 no new info
9         information7 no new info
10        information8 no new info
```

and this is the result I need:

```
               content         content_new
1          my new info         no new info
2         information2         no new info
3         information3         no new info
4         information4         no new info
5  my new information2 my new information2
6  my new informatino3 my new informatino3
7         information5         no new info
8         information6         no new info
9         information7         no new info
10        information8         no new info
```

The rule I want to implement is: if content includes "new information", put the value in content_new.
I tried this code:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- mutate(df, content_new = ifelse(grepl("new information",content,fixed==FALSE) == TRUE,content,content_new))
```

I get this error:

```
Error in function (string)  : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can solve this problem? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `fixed = FALSE` instead of `fixed == FALSE`:

```
mutate(df, content_new = ifelse(grepl("new information", content, fixed = FALSE),
                                content, content_new))
               content         content_new
1          my new info         no new info
2         information2         no new info
3         information3         no new info
4         information4         no new info
5  my new information2 my new information2
6  my new informatino3         no new info
7         information5         no new info
8         information6         no new info
9         information7         no new info
10        information8         no new info
```

Comment: I knew it would turn out to be something like that! I completely overlooked. Thank you for your quick answer!